# How to communicate with BLOB data type of sqlite efficiently in JDE 6.0

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I am using the Blackberry JDE 6. I am working with the blob data type using sqlite, and I found the API supports Database.createBlobOutputStream and Database.createBlobInputStream in JDE 7.0.  These methods work efficiently with memory to avoid out of memory problems. Can anybody suggest to me how to achieve the same effect with the pre-7.0 APIs?